# C# Outlook Plugin - Detect when recurring meeting is deleted

Tags: c#, plugins, outlook

I need my plugin to detect when a recurring meeting is deleted. My problem is the BeforeDelete event is fired off in the same manner if I delete just one of the occurrences in the set or if I delete the entire set. I need to know when a user is deleting the entire set and not just a single occurrence with in it. Is there a variable in Item that gives reference to this?

```
public void MailItem_BeforeDelete(object Item, ref bool Cancel) {

     Outlook.AppointmentItem MailItem = Item as Outlook.AppointmentItem;

     //Somewhere in this little guy [MailItem] should be something telling me if the 
     //item that is being deleted is a single occurance or is the entire set that is being deleted?
     //MailItem.IsRecurring is true in both instances so thats doesnt work. 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `RecurrenceState` property.

From the documentation, this property is set to the `OlRecurrenceState` enumeration:

- olApptMaster:    1 - The appointment is a master appointment.
- olApptOccurrence:    2 - The appointment is an occurrence of a recurring appointment defined by a master appointment.

Here are a couple of links to the documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/appointmentitem-recurrencestate-property-outlook

https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/olrecurrencestate-enumeration-outlook

Comment: Perfect!.. Thank you